# How to query MongoDB in Java using variables

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

After going through all the tutorials on the MongoDB site, I am still unable to write a simple query that uses an index to search for a keyword.

Here, I believe I am creating an index based on the "title" column (aka Fields). Wherever you see PARAMETER, it is a value passed in by the user. Additionally, I am looking in another "year" Field to further filter the result by date passed in by the user. This does not work and I can't seem to figure out a path forward.

```
        collection.createIndex(Indexes.text("title"));
        long matchCount = collection.countDocuments(and(Filters.text(PARAMETER), eq("year", PARAMETER)));
        System.out.println("Text search matches: " + matchCount);
```

Comment: It will help if you can post a sample document you are trying to search. Also, include the value of the field `PARAMETER`.